# How to recover a standalone MongoDB after an unexpected shutdown on k8s

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, share

After an unexpected power failure, the mongodb service I deployed on k8s could not be restarted normally. The log of mongodb showed that there was a problem with its data and could not be started.

I did not record the specific error log.

Comment: The general idea is that you ask a standalone question and then write an answer. This mixup is not exactly ideal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an attempt to write a self-answered question gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my fix:

### First

change k8s deployment.yaml config.

Because we want to repair the data file of mongodb, the first step is to make the mongo pod run, we run the command in the pod.

Now change the startup command of the container:

```yaml
 containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo:latest
        command:  ["sleep"]
        args: ["infinity"]
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        # .......
```

After apply it.
If I guessed correctly, the mongo pod should be up and running.

### Second

Use mongod command to repair data.

```bash
kubectl exec -it <YOURPODNAME> -- mongod --dbpath <YOURDBPATH> --repair --directoryperdb
```

I have to exec it with `--directoryperdb`, if you run it error, you can try remove it.

If I guessed correctly, So far everything is fine.

### Third

Recover k8s deployment.yaml, back to the way they were.

Now reapply it.

---------- Manual split line

The above is my repair process. Its worked for me. I just record it. You can refer to it to fix your mongodb. Thank you.